# My app icon disappears by sending apk to others

Tags: android, icons, apk, visibility, distribution

I have the following problem using android studio:
I have finished my app and everything is ok when I test it on my android smartphone with the emulator connected by USB.
Then I have sent the apk to a friend for testing and he found out that there was no application icon on the screen.
What can be the reason?
Is the icon only visible in the apk in google play store?
How can I be sure that it is visible when publishing it in the play store?
Or is the reason that I have not defined a round icon but only a rectangular?
Is it necessary to define a round icon (which does not look well for my icon)?
If I do not define a round Icon have I to define the rounded_icon like the rectangular or can I leave the basic android icon or have I to delete the rounded icon property?

I know a lot of questions but arising only from one.
Thank you for help.
bernd

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send to other people your app then you need to Build apk and then sent to anybody 
Go to Build/Build apk 
and then build that app and sent to anybody

they can install app like any other app.

Their is no problem on defining only round icon

TO generate only square icon click on 
new/image asset/
and then go to legacy to generate only square icon

Comment: I did it with Build apk and sent it, but the icon is not there, when the other person has installed the app, whereas the Icon is in my emulation via USB to my android phone.